# adxstudio Dynamics crm slow performance

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-online, adxstudio-portals

Is there a way we can improve performance when reading products from CRM using the adxstudio commerce portal?

Want to implement shopping cart functionality which is built-in in ADXstudio, but I am having issues with page load time. Output cache is already enabled on pages per user.

Comment: open a ticket to microsoft

Comment: done that thanks Alex